# Unable to resolve javax.xml.xquery.XQException

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xquery

On trying to parse an xml with Xquery i am getting the following exception, **javax.xml.xquery.XQException: A processing instruction must not be named 'xml' in any combination of upper and lower case. Syntax error on line 1 at column 1 of  near {...rsion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8...} 
  XPST0003: A processing instruction must not be named 'xml' in any combination of upper and
  lower case**. Given below is the XML file. Can someone please suggest what needs to be done here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Comment: Which software do you use exactly? How do you use it exactly do produce that error? You have tagged the question with [tag:java] and [tag:xquery], if you have written any Java and/or XQuery code that generates that error then show us minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like your XQuery processor chokes on the `<?xml` declaration, which is definitely not normal.

Comment: Which XQuery processor did you use?

Comment: i am using Java-based Saxon XQuery processor to process the XML file

Comment: Show us your Java code and XQuery code, the above is an XML document, if you want to run it through any XQuery processor using XQuery you would use e.g. `doc('file.xml')` in the XQuery code, that is, load the XML document with the `doc` function.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have presented an XML file to the XQuery processor when it is expecting an XQuery file. Most things in XML are also valid in XQuery, but the XML declaration is an exception. (It would be recognized as a processing instruction, except that processing instructions named "xml" are not allowed).

Check how you are invoking your XQuery processor. You're supplying an XML data file where it expects a query.

Comment: That's correct, i have presented an XML file and i am really not sure how an Xquery file looks like. Can you provide a sample of the same or modify the above XML into an XQuery file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a bit like presenting a COBOL program to a Java compiler, and when it goes wrong, saying "I don't know much about Java, can you give me some examples".

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

XQueryMain.java (java)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQConnection;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQDataSource;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQException;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQPreparedExpression;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQResultSequence;
import com.saxonica.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource;

public class XQueryMain {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      try {
          InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("condition.xqy"));
          XQDataSource dataSource = new SaxonXQDataSource();
          XQConnection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
          XQPreparedExpression preparedExpression = connection.prepareExpression(inputStream);
          XQResultSequence resultSequence = preparedExpression.executeQuery();

          while (resultSequence.next()) {
             System.out.println(resultSequence.getItemAsString(null));
          }
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException | XQException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

condition.xqy (XQuery)

```
for $x in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price=30
return $x/title
```

bookstore.xml (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

following jar files (SaxonHE9-9-0-2J) add to class path

- saxon9he.jar
- saxon9-test.jar
- saxon9-xqj.jar